# Does LoadBitMap() API creates paint issues?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a legacy system written in `C++`, `MFC`. 
I was checking a piece of code where [`LoadBitmap()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145033(v=VS.85).aspx) was replaced with [`LoadImage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045(VS.85).aspx) API. The comment written in the code says "`LoadBitmap()` uses the Paged pool from Kernel memory and if the usage reaches the maximum limit then the paint issues would pop up. So `LoadImage` API should be used".

I googled a bit on this but didn't get much information. When I checked the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145033(v=VS.85).aspx), they say "*Note that the use of LoadBitmap to load OEM bitmaps is deprecated and is supported only for backward compatibility*"

My questions are:
1. Are there any issues with `LoadBitmap()` API? Why should we prefer `LoadImage()` over `LoadBitmap()` ?
2. What is `OEM bitmaps`? Is there any issue if I load normal BMP with `LoadBitmap`?

Answer (score 3):

LoadBitmap() will only create display-compatible bitmaps, not device-independent bitmaps (DIBs).  And, as the [LoadBitmap() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145033.aspx) itself says, right at the top, "This function has been superseded by the **[LoadImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045.aspx)** function".  It's almost surprising that LoadBitmap() is still around, since I think it's been superseded by LoadImage() *since Windows 95!*  (Just goes to show how hard it is to drop backward-compatibility!)

OEM bitmaps are system-wide pre-defined images that can be requested by passing a NULL hInstance parameter and a magic lpBitmapName (like OBM_BTNCORNERS, OBM_CHECKBOXES, etc.).  These *used* to be used by Windows to draw various parts of the UI, but this is now handled by [DrawFrameControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162480.aspx).  Again, the OEM bitmaps are an old, old thing and the "new" behavior has been around for a long time.

Unless you have a strong reason to want to use LoadBitmap(), I'd follow the documented suggestion and use LoadImage().  To get LoadBitmap()-equivalent behavior, use:

```
LoadImage(hInstance, lpBitmapName, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
```

In new code you'd probably actually want a device-independent bitmap, in which case you **have** to use LoadImage(), and the last argument should be "LR_CREATEDIBSECTION".  In your case of having legacy code, sticking with "LR_DEFAULTCOLOR" may be safer.